# Finding all possible quadratic equations from two points

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to find all of the possible quadratic equations that can be found within a certain scenario.

In this scenario, there are two static Cartesian points, and then there is a dynamic integer value. The two points are points that all quadratic equations must go through in order to qualify, and the integer value changes something in the function that changes the shape. An example of what I mean can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/4o5pch1q/4/

Right now, I have these equations for the coefficients:

```
xtwo = (75 - slider) / 50;
xone = (slider - 25) / 50;
xzero = (slider - 25) / 25;
```

but I need a more adaptable equation

Basically, I want to find the general equation that expresses all equations that can be found from the above scenario, please.

Here's what I have so far:

a * x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + b * x<sub>1</sub> + c = 0

a * x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + b * x<sub>2</sub> + c = 0

a * x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + b * x<sub>1</sub> = a * x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + b * x<sub>2</sub>

b = a * (x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)

a * x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + a * (x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> - x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) * x<sub>1</sub> + c = 0

But that doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general form of the parabolic functions (with a vertical axis) is

```
f(x) = ax² + bx + c
```

You impose that the points `(x₁,y₁)` and `(x₂,y₂)` must belong to the graph of the function.

That is,

```
y₁ = ax₁² + bx₁ + c
y₂ = ax₂² + bx₂ + c
```

From these we obtain

```
c = y₁ - ax₁² - bx₁
y₂ = ax₂² + bx₂ + (y₁ - ax₁² - bx₁) = a(x₂²-x₁²) + b(x₂-x₁) + y₁
```

With that restrictions, we can get rid of the parameters `b` and `c`:

```
    y₂ - y₁ - a(x₂² - x₁²)   y₂-y₁
b = ────────────────────── = ───── - a(x₁+x₂)
           x₂ - x₁           x₂-x₁

                y₂-y₁                       y₂-y₁
c = y₁ - ax₁² - ─────x₁ + a(x₁+x₂)x₁ = y₁ - ─────x₁ + ax₁x₂
                x₂-x₁                       x₂-x₁
```

So we have

```
             ┌ y₂-y₁            ┐                y₂-y₁
f(x) = ax² + │ ───── - a(x₁+x₂) │x + y₁ - ax₁² - ─────x₁ + a(x₁+x₂)x₁
             └ x₂-x₁            ┘                x₂-x₁
```

Simplifying a little,

```
       ┌          y₂-y₁ ┐                
f(x) = │a(x-x₂) + ───── │(x-x₁) + y₁
       └          x₂-x₁ ┘
```

Varying `a` you get all the possible functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. You're last equation gives you **c** in terms of **a**. Your second to last equation gives you **b** in terms of **a**. Substituting both of those into your general equation gives you all three coefficients in terms of **a**. Then **a** is the dynamic integer value you want to shape your curve.